# What may cause the unexpected behavior with bitmap filter?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-image, android-bitmap, imagefilter

I have a problem with a function to adjust bitmap contrast.

This function is being set by 2 seekbars, when I change the first value on a seekbar everything is fine, but when value is from 0 to 99 on a second seekbar nothing is changing. Only if the value is 100 the bitmap is changing and gets the contrast effect.

```
public Bitmap applyRGBFilters2(Bitmap src, int valueContrast, int valueBrightness){
    int width = src.getWidth();
    int height = src.getHeight();
    Bitmap bmOut = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, src.getConfig());
    int A, R, G, B;
    int pixel;

    double contrast = Math.pow((100 + valueContrast) / 100, 2);

    for(int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
        for(int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
            pixel = src.getPixel(x, y);
            A = Color.alpha(pixel);

            R = Color.red(pixel);
            R = (int)(((((R / 255.0) - 0.5) * contrast) + 0.5) * 255.0);
            if(R < 0) { R = 0; }
            else if(R > 255) { R = 255; }

            G = Color.green(pixel);
            G = (int)(((((G / 255.0) - 0.5) * contrast) + 0.5) * 255.0);
            if(G < 0) { G = 0; }
            else if(G > 255) { G = 255; }

            B = Color.blue(pixel);
            B = (int)(((((B / 255.0) - 0.5) * contrast) + 0.5) * 255.0);
            if(B < 0) { B = 0; }
            else if(B > 255) { B = 255; }

            bmOut.setPixel(x, y, Color.argb(A, R, G, B));
        }
    }


    Bitmap bmOut2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmOut);
    Bitmap bmOut3 = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, bmOut2.getConfig());

    for(int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
        for(int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
            pixel = bmOut3.getPixel(x, y);
            A = Color.alpha(pixel);
            R = Color.red(pixel);
            G = Color.green(pixel);
            B = Color.blue(pixel);

            R += valueBrightness;
            if(R > 255) { R = 255; }
            else if(R < 0) { R = 0; }

            G += valueBrightness;
            if(G > 255) { G = 255; }
            else if(G < 0) { G = 0; }

            B += valueBrightness;
            if(B > 255) { B = 255; }
            else if(B < 0) { B = 0; }

            bmOut3.setPixel(x, y, Color.argb(A, R, G, B));
        }
    }
    return bmOut3;
}
```

Do you see any wrong things here?

Comment: I think your problem is here: (100 + valueContrast) / 100 and valueContrast is integer. Therefore you can only have 1 (valueContrast from 0 to 99) and 2 (valueContrast = 100). Change any 100 to 100.0 Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you very much! I was working on this for a long time and I didn't notice such a simple mistake. Greetings :)